# Running count of duplicate values

Tags: sql-server, powerbi, dax

I have a table showing pallets and the amount of product ("units") on those pallets. Individual pallets can have multiple records due to multiple possible defect codes. This means when I am trying to sum the total units on all pallets, the same pallet could get counted more than once, which is undesirable. I would like (but don't know how) to add a running tally column to show how many times a specific pallet ID has appeared so that I can filter out any record where the count is greater than 1:

```
| Pallet_ID | Units | Defect_Code | COUNT |
+-----------+-------+-------------+-------+
| A1        | 100   | 03          | 1     |
| A1        | 100   | 05          | 2     |
| B1        | 95    | 03          | 1     |
| C1        | 300   | 05          | 1     |
| C1        | 300   | 06          | 2     |
| D1        | 210   | 03          | 1     |
| A1        | 100   | 10          | 3     |
| D1        | 210   | 03          | 2     |
```

In the above example, the correct sum total of units should be 705. A solution in SQL or in DAX would work (although I lean towards SQL). I have searched for a long time but could not find a solution that fits this particular scenario. Many thanks in advance for your time and consideration!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may use the windowing function `row_number()`  with the `over` clause where you `partition by` the pallet. Within each partition you can control which row is assigned the number 1 by using the `order by` inside the over clause.

```
select
*
from (
    select 
      Pallet_ID 
    , Units 
    , Defect_Code
    , row_number() over(partition by Pallet_ID order by defect_code) as count_of
    from yourtable
    ) 
where count_of = 1
```

Note I have arbitrability use the column defect_code to order by as I don't know what other columns may exist. If your table has a date/time value for when the row was created you could use this instead, or perhaps the unique key of the table.

side note:
I would not recommend using column alias of "count" as it's a SQL reserved word